# Is there a way to call generic managers (e.g. syncdb, flush) from custom managers in django?

Tags: django, django-managers

For testing purposes, I'm writing a custom manager to reset the whole database, and repopulate certain tables with default fields. At the moment, I do this by calling mange.py flush, followed by manage.py loaddata, followed by the custom manager (that does some fancier stuff). I'd like to bring those all inside a single custom manager.

Is there a way to call generic managers (e.g. flush, loaddata) from my custom manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you talking about [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)? (different to [managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/))

something like

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('loaddata', 'myapp')
```